# Identity comparison returning 'True' for objects which are not 'interned'

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, comparison-operators

I am using `IDLE Shell 3.10` and writing my code in a file and running it.

I have written following code to compare identity of two objects.

```
print('\n Compare object identity of objects which are not interned')
x1 = 258656565
y1 = 258656565
print('{0} is {1}'.format(x1, y1), x1 is y1)
```

I am getting the output as `True`

As per my understanding the objects `x1 and y1` don't fall in the range `-5 to 256` and are not interned. That is why, comparing the identity should return `False`

Comment: Well, I am getting `False` as output in my google colab

Comment: I am using `IDLE Shell 3.10`

Comment: I get `False` when I try it the idle, but `True` when I put into a file and run it, so I guess the interpreter/compiler optimize it and create the number only once

Comment: How come interpreter is optimizing it when I put my code in a file? I am not getting that part

Comment: the interpreter, when reading from a file can compile the code into byte code and generate .pyc file if necessary, and while doing so can optimize part of it such as constants, common use cases and who know what else, thing that can't be done in an interactive session because there is no way to know what the user will come up with

Comment: `is` is simply not a meaningful thing to do with ints.  It doesn't tell you anything about the objects that you should care about at all.